# AWS share secret between accounts doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager, identity-management

In our configuration we have 2 accounts. One account "ACCOUNT_SECRET" is where the secrets are stored, and the other account "ACCOUNT_DEV" is where we have the IAM identities that authenticate to the EC2 instances.

For several reasons this configuration must be maintained in that way. The problem is that I keep receiving this error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_DEV:user/development-user is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: secret-name because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action

Well, I followed the following instructions:

- https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/secrets-manager-share-between-accounts
- https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/security/how-to-access-secrets-across-aws-accounts-by-attaching-resource-based-policies/

But for some reason that I don't understand is not working, and I have tried it in a bunch of different ways. Here are the last 3 policies that I have used to obtain the secrets:

#### KMS policy

I'm using a custom KMS to be able to edit its policy. It has several statements that allow some users of ACCOUNT_SECRET to perform kms actions, and I appended at the end this statement to allow the user of ACCOUNT_DEV to decrypt using this KMS.

```json
{
    "Sid": "Allow Tenants Use Of The Key",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": 
            "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_DEV:user/development-user"
    },
    "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
    ],
    "Resource": 
        "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_SECRET:key/keyID"
    
}
```

#### Resource based policy in the secret

Using the amazon console I go to the secret and I set this policy:

```json
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_DEV:user/development-user"
    },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret" ],
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

#### Identity based policy in ACCOUNT_DEV

And finally I attach a policy to the IAM identity user that is going to retrieve the secret and use the KMS key to decrypt it:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetSecretValue",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_SECRET:secret:secret-name*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowKMSDecrypt",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_SECRET:key/keyID"
        }
    ]
}
```

But none of this is working.

Also, I have checked if there are other policies in the ACCOUNT_DEV user that are denying the retrieval of secrets, but there are only policies related to s3 services.

Comment: `"arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_SECRET:secret:secret-name"` you may need to add a `*` to the end of that ARN as secrets' versions get stuff on the end of the ARN

Comment: @erik258 Thanks for your answer but I had tried it. Currently in my actual secret permission policy there is this wildcard `*`character.

Answer (score 0):

Your KMS key policy should be like the following

```
{
    "Sid": "Allow Tenants Use Of The Key",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": 
            "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_DEV:user/development-user"
    },
    "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
    ],
    "Resource": 
        "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_SECRET:key/keyID"
    
}
```

And IAM Policy in Dev Account

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetSecretValue",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_SECRET:secret:secret-name*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowKMSDecrypt",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_SECRET:key/keyID"
        }
    ]
}
```

The secret policy can be like this,

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_DEV:user/development-user"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```